# Vuejs how create a new array to pass to a graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I am using Vue js and need to create a new array after an Axios call to pass to a graph, which I am using Google Charts.

I get this result from the axios call:

```
[{ "id": "7", "item": "item 1", "month": "6", "sum": "3" },
{ "id": "8", "item": "item 2", "month": "6", "sum": "1" },
{ "id": "6", "item": "item 3", "month": "6", "sum": "3" },
{ "id": "5", "item": "item 4", "month": "6", "sum": "5" },
{ "id": "4", "item": "item 5", "month": "6", "sum": "19" }]
```

And need to create an array in this format, (**EDIT:**) having fixed in the first line the word "Month", following the listing the items. In the second line I need to have the month name (based on the month number) and the sum column values :

```
['Month', 'item 5', 'item 4', 'item 3'],
['June', 19, 5, 3],
```

I try to use a for after an axios call:

```
this.axios.post('Mycontroller/getCountByMonth',{
}).then((response) => {
        this.dataMonth = response.data.dataMonth;
        console.log('getList 2', this.dataMonth )
    for (i = 0; i < this.dataMonth; i++) { 
          console.log('getList 3')
          console.log(' >> ', this.dataMonth[i])
        }
```

I debug and see that it even does not enter into the for loop.

Using typeof I see the variable is an object.

How can I create the array into the expected format, from the object which results from the axios call?

Comment: It's not at all clear (to me) how you got from the first array to the second. Where did item 2 and item 1 go? Also, you say that `typeof i` says that it's an object? That doesn't make sense since it's set to 0 (it should be `for (let i = 0...`, by I digress).  Please do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.dataMonth))` and show some sample data.

Comment: this is the output of JSON.stringify : [
{"id":"7","item":"item 1","month":"6","sum":"3"},
{"id":"8","item":"item 2","month":"6","sum":"1"},
{"id":"6","item":"item 3","month":"6","sum":"3"},
{"id":"5","item":"item 4","month":"6","sum":"5"},
{"id":"4","item":"item 5","month":"6","sum":"19"}
]

Comment: Then it's an array and saying `i < this.dataMonth` doesn't make a lot of sense. When is a number less than an array? I think you want `i < this.dataMonth.length`

Comment: agree!! i just write length again, but still did not enter into the loop

Comment: Then there's something else wrong that's not apparent from the code you've shared. Try to create a [mcve] of just the loop part and see if you can narrow down the issue.

Comment: i wil create a  codepen

Answer (score 0):

Lets go a step back.
The result from your Request is that one.

```
{ "id": "7", "item": "item 1", "month": "6", "sum": "3" }
{ "id": "8", "item": "item 2", "month": "6", "sum": "1" }
{ "id": "6", "item": "item 3", "month": "6", "sum": "3" }
{ "id": "5", "item": "item 4", "month": "6", "sum": "5" }
{ "id": "4", "item": "item 5", "month": "6", "sum": "19" }
```

This is NOT valid JSON.
This is [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/) (JSON Lines)

```
var myArrayData = [];
myJSONLResult.split('\n').map(function (row) {
    var resultRowAsArray = JSON.parse(row);
    myArray.push(resultRowAsArray);
});
```

Now you can move on and process `myArrayData` as you like with some loops or Array-Functions.

Comment: See [OP's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588021/vuejs-how-create-a-new-array-to-pass-to-a-graph#comment99754131_56588021) about the result of `JSON.stringify()`. Looks like they do actually have a proper array